# Selecting a grease pencil object Blender 2.8

Tags: selection-tools, grease-pencil, layers, outliner

[image: Blender 2.8 grease pencil]In grease pencil mode I was practicing making eyes. My question isn't about that though. I'm having trouble selecting objects that I make. I have each colored object on it's own layer. All colored objects are under one stroke.  What am I missing. I would assume I could just click on each layer and move or animate it. However I cannot select either colored object. I can only move them all at once by selecting the stroke in the outliner. Should I make each object under one stroke each? Can layers be be selected individually? I am able to select the colored shapes in edit mode, but not in object mode. How can I move these colored shapes in order to animate them?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would suggest is to:

TAB into editmode
Lock the grease pencil layers you don't want to move (Click the pad lock in layers box)
Select all items in 3D view
Transform them as you would like.